# Laravel Pretty URL's wont work

Tags: .htaccess, laravel-5.1

I'm trying to remove 'index.php' of my project's url, but nothing works. I've been messing up with my .htaccess for weeks, but nothing.. nothing works! I have no idea of what is wrong.  mod_rewrite is indeed enabled. Here's the content of my .htaccess under public dir:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteBase /var/www/html/arquivos/index.php/
  <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
  </IfModule>

  RewriteEngine On

  # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
  RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

  # Handle Front Controller...
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Any suggestions? Thanks.

EDIT: My directory structure:

```
/var/www
  laravelproject/
    public/
      index.php
      main.cs
      ...
  html/ (apache server public folder)
    project (sym link to /var/www/laravelproject/public/)
```

I can access my project through this url:

localhost/project/index.php/

What i want to do is remove "index.php" out of my url.

Comment: This can be useful for you... http://tutsnare.com/remove-public-from-url-laravel/

Comment: I'll try this solution, but in my case, `localhost/laravelproject/index.php` works but `localhost/laravelproject/public` doesnt.

Comment: May be `index.php` file is missing into the `public` folder or your `.htaccess` file is doing something wrong.

Comment: It did not work, updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

I would just comment this but i can't. See if this can help in any way https://medium.com/laravel-news/the-simple-guide-to-deploy-laravel-5-application-on-shared-hosting-1a8d0aee923e#.nzycje9pc

Comment: I read that a couple of days ago, it did not help at all. I think I have to mess with my htaccess a little. BTW, such "link only" responses are not encouraged.

Comment: Yeah I know they are not but i was 1 point of being able to comment.